# del -rf ../public/{js,css,img} && vue-cli-service build --no-clean | Parameter format not correct - "public"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-vue

I am using vue in laravel. npm run watch is working fine to me, But when I am creating a build out of it, it throwing me the following error.

```
> frontend@0.1.0 build C:\wamp64\www\laravel-vue\laravel-vue-cli-3\frontend
> del -rf ../public/{js,css,img} && vue-cli-service build --no-clean

Parameter format not correct - "public".
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 build: `del -rf ../public/{js,css,img} && vue-cli-service build --no-clean`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-18T12_40_47_194Z-debug.log
```

This is my package.json file

```
    {
      "name": "frontend",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "del -rf ../public/{js,css,img} && vue-cli-service build --no-clean",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
      },
}
```

Comment: If you put something in a JSON file, make sure it's JSON.

Comment: I got the issue actually. Actually, the issue is with cmd in Windows, When I ran the same command in git bash it worked fine for me.